# Importing Azure Active Directory groups on Terraform

Tags: azure-active-directory, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Using the azuread provider from Terraform, I am trying to create groups reading a CSV file like this:

```
display_name
Group1
Group2
Group3
```

Reading it in a local variable:

```
locals {
  departments      = csvdecode(file("${path.module}/aad_departments.csv"))
}
```

```
# Create groups
resource "azuread_group" "groups" {
  for_each = { for group in local.departments : group.display_name => group }
  display_name = each.value.display_name
  prevent_duplicate_names = true
}
```

But I would like to import an existing group, "Group2", that already exists. I have used this command:

`terraform import azuread_group.groups xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx`

But when I plan and apply this terraform script it throws an error saying that the group already exist:

"To be managed via Terraform, this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azuread_group" for more information."

How can I import it?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are using a [`for_each`](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/for_each)  meta-argument to loop.

I am expecting `{ for group in local.departments : group.display_name => group }` would result in the below construct.

```
{
  "group1" = {
    "display_name" = "group1"
  }
  "group2" = {
    "display_name" = "group2"
  }
  "group3" = {
    "display_name" = "group3"
  }
}
```

You also need to add either [`security_enabled`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/group#security_enabled) or [`mail_enabled`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azuread/latest/docs/resources/group#mail_enabled) in your terraform code as per your requirements.

reference error message : `"security_enabled": one of`mail_enabled,security_enabled `must be specified`

```
resource "azuread_group" "groups" {
  for_each = { for group in local.departments : group.display_name => group }

  display_name            = each.value.display_name
  prevent_duplicate_names = true
  security_enabled        = true
   #### OR #####
  # mail_enabled            = true
}
```

Finally, you have to use the below three commands to import the 3 groups in your state file.

```bash
terraform import 'azuread_group.groups["group1"]' "<object_id>" # to import group1
terraform import 'azuread_group.groups["group2"]' "<object_id>" # to import group2
terraform import 'azuread_group.groups["group3"]' "<object_id>" # to import group3
```

Just for the safer side, you can use `terraform console` and verify the value of construct out of `{ for group in local.departments : group.display_name => group }` and adapt the commands/code accordingly.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you very much @ishuar :) Just one thing: I had to import it in this way:

terraform import azuread_group.admin_groups[\"SISCLD\"] <object_id>

With \" to set the key.

Thank you! :)